# Koin NoBeanDefFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, multi-module, koin, koin-scope

Long story short, I am facing strange app crashes with NoBeanDefFoundException, but it happens randomly. For some devices it works as expected and for others just crashes.

I have a multi module project with lots of koin modules and it worked as expected. But with app growing I decided to refactor it a bit and use scopes. In the project I have 4 types of scope:

- root (created by Koin)
- scope_activity
- scope_flow
- scope_fragment

I use scope linking to resolve parent's dependencies. E.g. scope_fragment -> scope_flow -> scope_activity -> root.
Also I load modules partially.

Below I provide a pice of code, so you can get the context.

Here is how I declare modules:

```
val categoryDataModule = module {
    // here is root scope
    single<CategoryRepository> {
        CategoryRepositoryImpl(get(), get(), Dispatchers.Default)
    }
}


val categoryDomainModule = module {
    scope(named(DI.SCOPE_FRAGMENT)) {
        // this use case requires CategoryRepository implementation
        factory<GetFollowedCategoriesUseCase> { GetFollowedCategories(get()) }
    }
}
```

I've created a unit test 'checkModules' and it fails with NoBeanDefFoundException. Tried to debug it and found that the root scope here has only 2 dependencies in `_instanceRegistry`. They are Application and Context.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CheckModulesTest : KoinTest {

    @Test
    fun checkAllModules() {
        koinApplication {
            androidContext(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
            modules(
                listOf(
                    categoryDataModule,
                    categoryDomainModule
                )
            )
        }.checkModules()
    }
}
```

So my question is how to fix it? Probably I am using scopes in the wrong way.

Comment: What are parameters you pass to CategoryRepositoryImpl, did you provide it?

Comment: @CôngHải yes I provide them. If I wasn't, then other exception would appear with message "Could not create instance".